# .net core request too large

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I have a `.net core 3.1` application I'm running on localhost. I'm sending over a List of 50k objects with 50 properties.

The response I'm getting is `REQUEST IS TOO LARGE` from the server I POST to.

I've tried editing startup.cs with the following

```
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>

        {

            options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;

        });



        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>

        {

            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;

        });



        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>

        {

            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;

            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;

            x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;

        });
```

How ever all three have failed. How can I increae the request body limit?

Comment: yes, but how can I configure that server to accept large requests. I am working on both servers.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that instead of changing the default post request maximum size you should send your objects in batches by 10k or by 5k, so each request fits the default maximum size. Changing IIS default values for requests can lead to nasty DOS exploits. However, if you want to change IIS's maximum request size anyway here is a tutorial on how to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/ i.e. you have to this in both the IIS settings of your operating systems and Startup.cs of your ASP.NET core application otherwise request will still be limit to 30000000 bytes no matter the settings in your Startup.cs

Comment: Could you please provide any tutorial link for sending and receiving in batches as you told. It is very helpful for us